# What versions of Windows Server support Windows Media Foundation's MP3 sink encoding?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server, ms-media-foundation

I can't quite figure out or find a comprehensive list that outlines whether or not encoding a file to MP3 will work on different versions of Windows Server if I am trying to use Windows Media Foundation's IMFSourceReader and IMFSinkWriter objects when specifying an AudioFormat encoding of MFAudioFormat_MP3 = "00000055-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71". Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only thing I have been able to find from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757927(v=vs.85).aspx is that the MP3 File Sink is supported in Windows 7, which does not help tell me much for server solutions.

Comment: I did not work with this to confirm reliably, but I suppose that supported MP3 sink is actually [MPEG-4 File Sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that is .MP4 file holding MP3 encoded audio track. And hence, Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @RomanR. But the MP3 file's header generated by Media Foundation contains no MP4 tags (ftypmp42, mp41isom, etc.), so I don't think it uses an MP4 container, because if it was, our audio player would not be able to play it. It must be MP3, as it has valid MP3 file headers like ID3, TFLT, etc.

Comment: It looks to me like it might be only Windows Server 2012 that supports MP3 encoding...